# Twitter/Linked integration was removed WP7.5

Tags: contacts, people-hub, linked-accounts, twitter

Has Microsoft removed twitter integration from peoples hub?..I was always reading twitter in peoples hub, with facebook and linked in. And one day twitter removed from my live account and when i checked peoples hub-there were no twitter updates too. So is it only me, or Microsoft officially removed Twitter integration?

Comment: Your phone is a normal one or you made some hacks? I had login problem when I tried to change Marketplace country.

Comment: I was changing marketplace country. Also ive renamed my LiveID without phone factory reset(changed some registry settings..) But why that can disable twitter integration, for example!?

Answer (score 2):

It has not been removed, and there are a few things you can check

1. Make sure you have an account linked up.
2. In the what's new section of the people hub, tap "what's new" and you will be given a list of accounts to filter.
3. In you settings, swipe to "applications", go to people, and click on "filter my contacts". Make sure the account is selected there.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few glitches before with this integration. After trying what Joe said first, you can go to your settings > email+accounts. Remove and re-add twitter.

This fixed twitter for me the last time it happened.

Comment: Cant remove twitter connection from the phone. Says: " we're having trouble deleting twitter."

Comment: Cant see twitter among services in my live account too...It was there, and it was added. Dont know why it disappeared.

Comment: I dont have twitter listed in my live services either, but it works fine. I dont think MS has to connect to twitter the same way it does to facebook. I'm assuming that it cant remove twitter because its looking to remove the currently signed in ID (which you never connected to twitter with). I fear you may need to sign back in with the other ID, remove twitter, re-sign in, and then add twitter.

Comment: settings > email+accounts .. There is no Twitter service listed too :(